# Large title hidden in ViewController even though properly set

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I'm having some issues with my NavigationController, specifically with the title. Even though I think I set up my large title correctly, it doesn't show correctly in the simulator.

Link to GitHub: [Github link](https://github.com/mattttis/Carrot)

I have tried:

- Restarting Xcode & the simulator
- Removing & re-adding the NavigationController
- Following code is attached for reference:

```
    navigationController?.title = "Groceries"
    self.navigationItem.title = "Groceries1"
    title = "Groceries2"
```

None of the above  resolved the issue. The problem only persists on the AccountViewController and the TableViewController, which are both connected to the TabBar.

Something that may be related:

```
self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: true)
```

It doesn't work either.
How can I make sure the title shows? (And if it's related: how can I make sure the back button is hidden?)

Thanks a lot.

[image: This is what shows in the simulator]

[image: My NavigationController]

[image: Settings for the title of TableViewController]

Comment: Just add following :- title = "My Title" in viewDidLoad and check

Comment: Your github project is missing "GoogleService-Info.plist". It means you dragged it into the project but failed to check "Copy items if needed".
I tried figuring out the issue without compiling the project but failed to make progress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was trying to edit the NavigationController's title, while the NavigationController was overridden by the TabBarController. I have managed to solve the issue by placing the following in the ViewWillAppear:

```
tabBarController?.title = "Groceries"
```

This has solved the issue. Thank you all for taking the time to look into the issue!

Answer (score 0):

I added
`title = "MMMMMM"` in **viewDidLoad** of LoginViewController and your code works fine at my end.
[image]

Comment: Hi. Thank you for taking the time to respond. After further examination it seems like the issue only exists on the ViewControllers that are connected to the tab bar, AccountViewController and TableViewController. The titles work perfectly on the other VC's. Would you mind taking a look at the AccountVC and the TableVC again? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it alternatively as well by using storyBoard.
Steps:

(1) Go to view controller in storyBoard.

(2) Go to Editor ->Embed in Navigation controller.

(3) Now in the view controller,select Navigation Item,go to Attribute
inspector and set your title.

If you have any other questions,feel free to ask.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for taking the time to respond! I've already tried that, but unfortunately it doesn't work: https://www.dropbox.com/s/y6o57h2q7f6a02d/Screenshot%202020-08-03%2020.26.04.png?dl=0